# Inequalities on positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I encountered the following question from *Problems and Solutions in Introductory and Advanced Matrix Calculus* by Steeb and Hardy [(P.39 Problem 3)](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/10135/suppl_file/10135_chap01.pdf).

> **Question.** Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a positive semi-definite matrix, and $u,v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ two unit vectors. Prove that $$(u^*v)(u^*Av)\ge 0.$$

However, I do not think this is true. For $n=1$, we have $A=[a]$ for some non-negative real number $a$. Write $u=[e^{i\theta}]$ and $v=[e^{i\phi}]$ for some $\theta,\phi\in(-\pi,\pi]$. Then $$(u^*v)(u^*Av)=ae^{i\cdot 2(\phi-\theta)}, $$ which needs not be a real number.

I am wondering if this inequality is true if the conditions are slightly modified. Any suggestions or comments are highly welcomed.

Comment: If $u=v$ then it is certainly true.

Comment: @Rammus I agree, but that is too trivial :)

Comment: @BernardPan When mentioning something from a book, please also mention the book in question in your question.

Comment: @BernardPan This question is asking to prove something that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

This exercise does not look correct. In fact, even if you pick $A=\alpha I$, $\alpha>0$, then you would get $\alpha(u*v)^2$ which is not necessarily real.

Considering instead $(v^*u)(u^*Av)$ fixes the problem in that case but does not generalize to other positive definite matrices.

I have been trying to fix the statement of the problem, to no avail. I will update my answer if I manage to come up with a slight modification that makes the problem meaningful.